# Scroll Down SFSafarViewController

Tags: ios, safari, wkwebview

I highly doubt it, but is there any way to scroll to a specific location in an SFSafariViewController? In a regular WKWebView, doing so is easy. All you need to call is `[self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 100)];`. I've also considered trying to get the SFSafariViewController to evaluate Javascript and do it that way like WKWebViews can. If this is not possible please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/), this is not the use case for `SFSafariViewController`.

> The user's activity and interaction with SFSafariViewController are not visible to your app, which cannot access AutoFill data, browsing history, or website data

If you need to interact with the web view, use a web view(`UIWebView` or `WKWebView`). `SFSafariViewController` is meant to provide browser features within an app. You do not have control over what is going on within the view.